# problems with arm-elf-gcc cross compiler on OS X

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, arm, cross-compiling

I'm trying to compile my first linux ARM hello world program and when I copy and run the binary to my target linux board (linuxstamp Atmel arm 9g20) I get "Illegal instruction"

I am running arm-elf-gcc-4.6 on OS X from macports. I am using Eclipse for and IDE. It looks like the build is more for a stand alone non OS program rather then code to run in linux user space. Could someone point me in the right direction? Thanks.

code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
    printf("hello world\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Build of configuration Release for project ArmTest **

make all 
Building target: ArmTest.elf
Invoking: ARM Mac OS X GCC C Linker
/opt/local/bin/arm-elf-gcc-4.6 -nostartfiles -Wl,-Map,ArmTest.map -mcpu=arm920 -mthumb -o"ArmTest.elf"  ./main.o
/opt/local/lib/gcc/arm-elf/4.6.0/../../../../arm-elf/bin/ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; defaulting to 0000000000008000
Finished building target: ArmTest.elf

Invoking: ARM Mac OS X GNU Create Flash Image
/opt/local/bin/arm-elf-objcopy -O binary ArmTest.elf "ArmTest.hex"
Finished building: ArmTest.hex

Invoking: ARM Mac OS X GNU Create Listing
/opt/local/bin/arm-elf-objdump -h -S ArmTest.elf >"ArmTest.lst"
Finished building: ArmTest.lst

Invoking: ARM Mac OS X GNU Print Size
/opt/local/bin/arm-elf-size  --format=berkeley ArmTest.elf
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
   8112    2104     232   10448    28d0 ArmTest.elf
Finished building: ArmTest.siz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am running arm-elf-gcc-4.6 on OS X from macports [...]
>   It looks like the build is more for a stand alone non OS program rather then code to run in linux user space.

Indeed, this is for embedded ARM devices **without** Linux OS. The Linux variant of gcc as cross compiler for ARM should have "linux" somewhere in its name like "arm-linux-gcc".